# how to do a 2/2 spotcolor in CMYK

Tags: color, cmyk

My sadistic offset printer has a reasonable price for a 2/2 spot color offset print, but not for full 4/4 color cmyk.  moreover, my 700-page book includegraphics-es many images and graphs created by R and even other people, which were not created by me but are in RGB and include some colors that are not within my 2/2 space.

So, I am now looking for the best way on macos to take my tex or pdf file, and do two things.  the first is to create a 2/2 file that my printer likes.  (are these usually two B-W or gray pdf's??)  the second is to see a representation of what will come out of the printer.  for example, if my spot color is magenta and there was some graph that had some cyan in it, if my printer ran it through 2/2, how would the result look like [i.e., with the cyan left blank]?

advice appreciated.

/iaw

Comment: The macro level can't change the colours in included graphics ...

Comment: I use Adobe Acrobat preflight to go from a full-color digital pdf book to grayscale to send to the print house (except for the cover, of course).